# Angular 11 POST request with both Query Parameter and Request Body

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, httpclient

I'm want to do an api call from my angular 11 app. What I want to do is send a post request to the api with a command param
The request containe one parameter and one body

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That's well described in the Angular's HTTPClient documentation https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: But my request type is not described

Comment: Why not just add idTier in the 'Note' object. If the Note object is from the database model, then you would need a DTO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 3rd picture you're missing a dollar sign

```
this.http.post(environment.CommercialAPI_SERVICE_URL+`Notes/Post_Note?idTier=${idTier}` , note)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write it like the following

```
this.http.post(environment.CommercialAPI_SERVICE_URL+`Notes/Post_Note?idTier={idTier}` , note)
```

Comment: I changed but do nothing

Comment: @ChakerAI when you debug the response in visual studio neither of them had been bind ?

Comment: When I send a request from Swagger it works will

Comment: @ChakerAI no no i mean when you sent the request as normal from the front-end side, did params :   idTier  and note was bind or not when you debug with vs  ??

Comment: I try it was not bind

Comment: @ChakerAI can you please give me a screenshot for the front-end side method  ?

Comment: I added the screenshot in my post you can see it